# How to Inherit or Extend Properties in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to extend the basic button component in Vue 3.3.4 to add custom props like variants and colors. However, I'm encountering errors when attempting to use either type intersections or interfaces.

```js
import { ButtonHTMLAttributes } from "vue";

type ButtonProps = ButtonHTMLAttributes & {
  variant?: "primary" | "secondary";
  color?: string;
};

defineProps<ButtonProps>();
```

```bash
20 |  type ButtonProps = ButtonHTMLAttributes & {
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
21 |    variant?: "primary" | "secondary";
22 |    color?: string;
```

This component by itself is quite simple, yet similar errors occur when using utilities like InstanceType. Also, VSCode doesn't show any possible problem.

```bash
19 |  type BaseButtonProps = InstanceType<typeof HTMLButtonElement>;
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Besides those examples, I'd like to be able to use at least something similar to React, where I can infer props from a base component and extend them with additional properties in a derived component. Something like this:

```
interface RoundButtonProps extends ComponentProps<typeof BaseButton> {}
```

Ps: It's been a long time since I've used React or Vue, so the examples may not be the most accurate or appropriate approach